# Opera extensions (widgets): dynamic config file

Tags: opera, opera-extension

I have an Opera 11 extension, which has a background process and an injected script. These communicate very frequently with a remote server (not the webpage the user's viewing), using the background script's cross-site XMLHttpRequest capabilities.

I would like the URL of the server to be a preference, so that it can be modified by the user without editing the package. The config.xml file would good, for it accepts `<preference name="serverUri" value="..." />`. However, I would like the script to be able to update itself directly from the server (not through Opera's site), which can be achieved using `<update-description href="http://myserver.com/client/update" />`.

So what I would like to do is have the `href` attribute of the `update-description` element to be dependent on the value of the preference `serverUri`. I would imagine some syntax like this:

```
<update-description href="{$serverUri}" />
```

But I could not find any references to this kind of functionality. Is there some way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use variables in the config.xml file as you've written and I don't think there are plans to add this.

I'm sure you know that preferences can be set not just with the `preference` element in config.xml but also using `widget.setPreferenceForKey(value, key)`, but I don't think that solves your problem in this case.

The only workaround I can think of is if you have all your logic in an external script on your server and in your extension's local files (background script or injected script), just have a very simple couple of lines that reference your external script. Something like:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://www.example.com/script.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

You could then make the script's URL editable by the user and store it in `widget.preferences`.

**EDIT by hallvors: This solution has serious drawbacks, see my comment below.**

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure that extensions can load external scripts that way, but it's a good thought, I'll give it a try. +1 for the suggestion.

Comment: I'd recommend against doing this - even if it works today we (Opera) might disallow it later, because adding scripts from the web inside your extension creates a security hole where an attacker might modify the script and achieve control of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not currently possible. It seems like a bit of an unusual use case, which could potentially be risky to implement, so it would be interesting to hear more about why you want to do this.

Comment: Without going too much into the details, the point would have been making it a product that's customizable through the server-side interface. The server-side application would generate the JS code for the extension, which would be applied as an update.
In the end I just did it the old-fashioned way, and built in the customization to the extension itself, but it's a lot less optimal solution than I was hoping for.
You're right, I haven't considered that this feature could potentially be used for malicious purposes. Thanks for pointing that out! It explains why there is no such feature.